# When I modify the js or html file, is there any way to not compile it?

Tags: magento2

I am modifying the js or html file in my localhost. I have to execute it every time.

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cache:clean

Is there any way to not compile it every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All files are linked to your `pub/static` folder. You can modify the `deployed` file in there.

For example: `Catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js` will be in `pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js`

This example assume you are using default Luma theme

The pub/static folder is `generated` so remember to save your changes into original file, otherwise, it will be clear after running deploy command.

Comment: It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Set developer mode

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

When developing, I make sure full_page cache is off. Usually, I also turn off block and layout cache too

```
bin/magento cache:disable full_page layout block_html
```

Usually you should see js or html changes immediately if those are off and developer mode set.

For css/less changes, you should remove static files. In developer mode, all these files are automatically recreated.

```
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*
```

Run those commands from magento2 root folder. Note - do NOT delete pub/static/.htaccess file as it is necessary.

Comment: Hi,  thank you for your comment.Follow your steps and i get an error.Warning: file_put_contents(E:\web/pub/static/frontend/ruby/ruby6/en_US/css/style.css): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\web\vendor\wikimedia\less.php\lessc.inc.php on line 177

Comment: This doesn’t look like a default magento file, I guess you have a custom theme? I think it might be caused by incorrect file permissions, but I can’t be sure. You can run bin/magento static:content:deploy -f again to see if the file gets generated, but you shouldn’t have to in developer mode.

Comment: This really helped me, thanks!